# Завершение процесса через определённое время

Tags: python, многопоточность, timeout

интересует такой вопрос,  как завершить запущенный процесс через определённое время. То есть, у меня есть функция обработки, она начинает работать и запускается процесс в системе, который может работать от 1 до 10 секунд, но если работает больше 10 секунд, процесс должен завершиться(мы должны его как-то "убить"). Сначала пытался использовать signal, но он только для Unix-систем, сейчас нашёл подобную тему  в модуле threading, но нормально реализовать не получается. У кого нибудь есть идеи или подобные наработки? Заранее спасибо.

По сути, в идеальном варианте надо сделать, чтобы thread1 работал не более 10 секунд, но как я понял закрыть поток принудительно нельзя, то есть получается надо ловить сам процесс? Или я немного не понимаю сути?

Прилагаю код (Это отладочный вариант и лишнее здесь будет убрано (через импорты можно отследить историю вариантов:))):

```
import os
import win32com.client
import zipfile
import threading
import sys
import pythoncom
import time
import subprocess

def process_exists(process_name):
    proc = subprocess.check_output(['TASKLIST']).decode('UTF-8', 'ignore').splitlines()
    #print(proc)
    for lines in proc:
        #print(lines)
        if process_name in lines:
            return True

def file_finder(directory = '', ext = '', function = ''):
    counter_good = 0
    for dir_path, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
        for file_name in files:
            file_path = os.path.join(dir_path, file_name)
            error_file_name = file_name
            file_name, file_extension = os.path.splitext(file_path)
            if file_extension.lower() == ext: # ext - отбираемое расширение (.xxx)
                if function == 'doc2docx':
                    thread1 = threading.Thread(target=doc2docx, args=(file_path, error_file_name, directory,))
                    thread2 = threading.Timer(10, process_exists, args = ('WINWORD.EXE',))
                    thread1.start()
                    thread2.strat()
                    print(thread1.is_alive())
                    print(threading.active_count()) 


                    thread1.join()
                    thread2.join()

                    print(thread1.is_alive())
                    #while thread1.is_alive() == True:
                        #time.sleep(10)
                        #print(process_exists('WINWORD.EXE'))
                        #if process_exists('WINWORD.EXE') == True:
                            #os.system('taskkill /f /im WINWORD.EXE')
                            #print('Процесс был завершён принудительно')
                        #else:
                            #print('Процесс был завершён самостоятельно')
                        #Убиваем winword                    


                    #thread1.join()
                    #print('Процесс завершён')
                    #doc2docx(file_path, error_file_name, directory)
                    counter_good +=1
                    print('Обработано:' + str(counter_good) + ' файлов')                    
                elif function == 'docx2xml':
                    docx2xml(file_path, file_name, error_file_name, directory)
                else:
                    print('Не выбрана фунция обработки')



def doc2docx(path, err_name, directory):    
    docx_file = '{0}{1}'.format(path, 'x')    
    pythoncom.CoInitialize()    
    try:    
        print('Идёт обработка', path.encode('ascii', 'ignore'))
        word = win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.application")
        word.visible = 0                
        wordDoc = word.Documents.Open(path, False, False, False)
        wordDoc.SaveAs2(docx_file, FileFormat = 16)
        wordDoc.Close()    
        os.remove(path)
    except:
        try:
            wordDoc.close()
        except:
            pass
        os.rename(path, directory + '\\!Необработанные\\' + err_name)
    finally:
        pythoncom.CoUninitialize()
```

Comment: приложите ваш код пожалуйста

Comment: То есть вопрос по сути "как из скрипта на питоне убить процесс, запущенный из этого же скрипта"? Как запускается этот подлежащий убиению процесс?

Comment: Прошу извинить, код приложил. Процесс запускается через win32com.client. Приложение конвертит .doc в .docx, но иногда попадаются файлы или выпадают исключения, которые "вешают" word, и надо принудительно закрывать процесс winword через диспетчер. Т.к. скрипт предполагает полную автономность, то необходим таймаут, для закрытия таких "висящих" процессов

Comment: Идеальный модуль для этого timeout_decorator, ноооо... Он только для UNIX-систем

Comment: Так убивать пробовали уже: _os.system('taskkill /f /im WINWORD.EXE')_ ?

Comment: Да, этот один из способов я уже отработал, но тут у меня получилось как, допустим ворд обработал файл успешно за ~1 секунду(всё как надо), но дальше ждём проверки условия (для примера мне надо 10 секунд) на существование процесса winword. То есть получается каждый файл будет вне зависимости от скорости ворда обрабатываться 10 секунд

Comment: Не моя область. В linux pthreads есть timed_join, который будет ждать завершения потока заданное время, после чего вывалится с ошибкой (и тогда мы можем, например, прибить поток). Здесь ничего подобного нет разве?

Comment: @tum_, он использует COM, а это по сути RPC

Comment: А СОМ, которого я не знаю, не имеет средств сообщить что-то "вызывателю" процесса, так надо понимать? Тогда тяжелый случай и нужно подумать о другом подходе, имхо...

Comment: [Вот тут](http://www.icodeguru.com/WebServer/Python-Programming-on-Win32/ch12.htm) если почитать главу Error Handling, то вроде как мы можем узнать статус выполнения? Если мы получили статус Success - ничего ждать не надо, сразу к следующему файлу. В противном случае - подождать N секунд и убить, сделав отметку в каком-нибудь журнале. Где я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Исключения я ловлю, успешно закрываю, работа продолжается. Но есть капля дегтя) есть файлы, которые идут допустим с паролем, тогда он просто открывает окно Ворда и ждёт введения этого пароля

Comment: выкладывайте уж сразу все случаи, которые "вешают" word... Если дело только в паролях, значит надо думать про пароли.   И что происходит в doc2docx в этом сценарии? Он никогда не доходит до wordDoc.SaveAs2(), останавливаясь на Open(), или что-то другое?

Comment: Решение выложил в ответах, сейчас как я себе вижу дальнейшее развитие, это брать и описывать все com__error'ы через try-except, и анализировать файлы, соответственно делая для них отдельные "ветки обработки"

Comment: Хотя мне всё таки интересно, неужели нету нормальной библиотеки под .doc файлы, прошерстил кучу форумов, в том числе и англоязычных, но я так понял, что для .doc формата, необходимы определенные "танцы". Сам пробовал с побайтовым чтением .doc, но терял форматирование и + надо искать "золотую" концовку текста в .doc, т.к. через раз обрезал содержимое, путая конец раздела и текстовой части. Поэтому в ход пошла тяжёлая артиллерия))

Comment: методы по реализации timeout для subprocess, threading, multiprocessing и конкретно ворда (win32com api) могут  отличаться. В заголовке вопроса попробуйте указать что вас в большей степени интересует. Если основная программа также выходит через timeout секунд, то это стоит упомянуть, так как упрощает некоторые варианты реализации.

Comment: Основная программа(скрипт) должна работать, пока не переберет все файлы, находящиеся в папке, то есть таймаут нужен именно для функции (процесса)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваша главная проблема - вы лупите по площадям, работая с процессом по имени - `winword.exe`. Ваша задача - получить PID этого процесса и отслеживать его в отдельном потоке таймера.

Структура получается такая:

- перед началом цикла запускаете поток с таймером;
- в основном цикле, после `word = win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.application")` получаете PID;
- передаете PID в поток таймера, и он начинает контролировать процесс по PID. Если в течение 10 секунд он ещё жив - прибивает его - и ждет новых заданий;
- выполняете операции с Word документом. Если зависли, поток с таймером прибъет Word процесс через 10 секунд;
- повторяете цикл для нового документа, тем временем поток таймера может все еще наблюдать за старым процессом. Вы можете ему сообщить, что уже больше не надо;

Для получения PID посмотрите этот кусок кода на VB.Net (взят [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17759478/9921853)):

```
'get the window handle
Dim xlHWND As Integer = xlApp.hwnd

'this will have the process ID after call to GetWindowThreadProcessId
Dim ProcIdXL As Integer = 0

'get the process ID
GetWindowThreadProcessId(xlHWND, ProcIdXL)
```

Используйте `win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd)` раз уж вы используете другие аналогичные модули.

Хотя ctypes мне кажется более предпочтительным, так как это встроенный в питон функционал: ctypes.windll.user32.GetWindowThreadProcessId

```
import ctypes
pid = ctypes.c_ulong()
ctypes.windll.user32.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, ctypes.pointer(pid))
```

Вообще говоря, при однопотоковой работе вам даже и PID не нужен. Подумаешь, снесет случайно Winword с вашим любимым, не сохраненным, документом. Но если Вам захочется конвертировать в несколько потоков, то тогда без PID не обойтись.

### Добавлено

Мда, с PID для Word оказалось несколько сложнее. Но тем не менее, вот полностью рабочий вариант:

```
import queue
import ctypes
import threading
import time
import uuid
import win32gui
import os
import win32com.client
import pythoncom

exit_flag = False
timer_reset = False

PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION = 0x0400
PROCESS_TERMINATE = 1


class Watchdog_Thread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue_lock, queue, timeout):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue_lock = queue_lock
        self.queue = queue
        self.timeout = timeout

    def run(self):
        global timer_reset
        global exit_flag

        while not exit_flag:

            # Waiting for task
            self.queue_lock.acquire()
            try:
                pid = self.queue.get_nowait()
                self.queue_lock.release()
            except queue.Empty as e:
                self.queue_lock.release()
                time.sleep(0.5)
                continue

            print("Started timer for process {}".format(pid))
            started = time.time()
            while True: # Waiting for timeout or process completion
                if timer_reset:
                    timer_reset = False
                    print("Process {} completed in {} seconds".format(pid, int(time.time()-started)))
                    break # Process completed, go wait for new task
                if started + self.timeout > time.time():
                    time.sleep(0.5)
                    continue

                # Kill the process
                handle = ctypes.windll.kernel32.OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE | PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, False, int(pid))
                ctypes.windll.kernel32.TerminateProcess(handle, -1)
                ctypes.windll.kernel32.CloseHandle(handle)
                print("Killed process {}".format(pid))
                break # Process killed, go wait for new task

work_queue_lock = None
work_queue = None

def file_finder(directory = '', ext = '', function = ''):
    global exit_flag
    global work_queue_lock, work_queue

    pythoncom.CoInitialize()
    try:
        # Create lock to work with queue (get/put actions)
        work_queue_lock = threading.Lock()
        # Create queue for the actions
        work_queue = queue.Queue()
        # Created watchdog thread
        watchdog_thread = Watchdog_Thread(work_queue_lock, work_queue, 10)
        watchdog_thread.start()

        counter_good = 0
        for dir_path, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
            if dir_path.lower().endswith('failed'): continue
            for file_name in files:
                file_path = os.path.join(dir_path, file_name)
                error_file_name = file_name
                file_name, file_extension = os.path.splitext(file_path)
                if file_extension.lower() == ext: # ext - отбираемое расширение (.xxx)
                    if function == 'doc2docx':
                        doc2docx(file_path, error_file_name, directory)
                        counter_good +=1
                        print('Processed:' + str(counter_good) + ' file(s)')
                    elif function == 'docx2xml':
                        docx2xml(file_path, file_name, error_file_name, directory)
                    else:
                        print('Не выбрана фунция обработки')

    except:
        print('Got exception')
    finally:
        exit_flag = True
        pythoncom.CoUninitialize()


def doc2docx(path, err_name, directory):
    global timer_reset
    docx_file = '{0}{1}'.format(path, 'x')    
    try:    
        print('Processing', path.encode('ascii', 'ignore'))
        word = win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.application")
        word.WindowState = 2 # wdWindowStateMinimize
        word.Caption = str(uuid.uuid1())
        word.Visible = True
        while True:
            hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, word.Caption)
            if hwnd: break
            time.sleep(0.05)
        word.visible = False

        pid = ctypes.c_ulong()
        _ = ctypes.windll.user32.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, ctypes.pointer(pid))

        work_queue_lock.acquire()
        work_queue.put(pid.value)
        work_queue_lock.release()

        wordDoc = word.Documents.Open(path, False, False, False)
        wordDoc.SaveAs2(docx_file, FileFormat = 16)
        wordDoc.Close()
        timer_reset = True
        os.remove(path)
    except:
        print('Got exception')
        try:
            wordDoc.close()
        except:
            pass
        os.rename(path, directory + '/failed/' + err_name)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    file_finder('c:/temp/test', '.doc', 'doc2docx')
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, да в моём решении подразумевается то, что на машине не будет перед этим запущено ни одного winword.exe процесса. Согласен, что можно отслеживать по PID, тогда эту брешь можно будет закрыть.  То есть получается мы с отслеживанием PID, сможем работать в несколько потоков? Но тогда при передачи файла программе при "пробежке по каталогу" необходимо будет обеспечить,то чтобы оба процесса не получили на вход один и тот же файл? Я правильно понимаю?

Comment: Хе-хе, оно всегда так подразумевается. А потом опаньки... Но, кстати, с многопоточностью COM серверов может и не получиться. Я добавил полностью рабочий вариант на основе моих идей.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение, аналог timeout_decorator, для win-семейства. Подсмотрел на соседнем киберфоруме, с минимальными изменениями прекрасно справляется со своей задачей. Но безусловно попробую вариант предложенный Sergey Nudnov. Т.к. буду бороться дальше за скорость).

```
import time
import functools
import threading

class ExceededError(Exception):
    pass

def timeout(seconds):
    def decorator(func):

        def run_with_timeout(*args, **kwargs):
            def target():
            """
            Обертка для выполнения функции в отдельном потоке
            """
                try:
                    result.extend((func(*args, **kwargs), 'ok'))
                except Exception as error:
                    result.extend((error, 'error'))

            result = []
            worker = threading.Thread(target=target)
            worker.daemon = True
            try:
                worker.start()
                worker.join(seconds)
            except Exception as error:
                print('Error starting thread')
                raise error

        # Проверяем результат выполнения целевой функции
            if not result:
                message = (
                'Функция "{}" выполнялась дольше,'.format(func.__name__) +
                ' чем было разрешено "{}" сек.'.format(seconds)
                 )
                raise ExceededError(message)
            else:
                if result[1] == 'error':
                    raise result[0]

        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            if seconds == 0:
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
            else:
                run_with_timeout(*args, **kwargs)

        return wrapper

    return decorator


@timeout(10)
def long_running_function():
    print('start')
    time.sleep(5)
    print('end')
    return [0.1]


print(long_running_function())
```